# video controller and Standard VGA graphics adapter

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, graphics-card

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 with Windows Vista Home Edition. I recently reinstalled my OS and lost the video controller and Standard VGA graphics adapter.

How can I reinstall it on my system?

Answer (score 1):

You should get any necessary drivers on Dell's support site for that product.

Look [here](http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?releaseid=R161378&fileid=216131) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Windows Update, and look for drivers in there.
Or if you want driver alone without service packs go to http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/ from system in question

Comment: It'd be more useful to get drivers directly from his video cards manufacturer.